# StageX and StageY off of stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I've come across a difficult problem, I have a vcam (virtual camera) that leads my player off the stage, which makes touch events work differently, because I use `var touchX = stageX` and `var touchY = stageY`, but this doesn't work when the view is off the stage.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please, my app's deadline is january 30th

Comment: @Lee Burrows var touchX = stageX and var touchY = stageY, but my character comes off the stage.

Comment: are you trying to stop character going off stage?

Comment: No, I want my character to go off the stage, and I want to know how to get the coordinates the user taps when off the stage.

Comment: how can user tap off the stage? post your code

Comment: I'm guessing it is a vcam that's following the player(?) try to change your var touchX = stageX to something like var touchX = stageX - vcam.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured you could do `e.localX + obj.x`.